# CloudWatch Agent is not starting on a Windows10, "unable to determine aws-region" message

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set AWS CloudWatch Agent on my laptop for training purposes. I followed the instructions, and my $env:ProgramFiles\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent file ended up:

```
{
    "agent":{
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "run_as_user": "Lenovo"
    },
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\winevt\\Logs\\Kaspersky Event Log.evtx",
                        "log_group_name": "Kaspersky_Event_Log.evtx",
                        "log_stream_name": "{hostname}",
                        "retention_in_days": -1
                    }
                ]
            },
            "windows_events": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "event_format": "xml",
                        "event_levels": [
                            "INFORMATION",
                            "WARNING",
                            "ERROR",
                            "CRITICAL"
                        ],
                        "event_name": "System",
                        "log_group_name": "System",
                        "log_stream_name": "{hostname}",
                        "retention_in_days": -1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "metrics": {
        "metrics_collected": {
            "LogicalDisk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Free Space"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Memory": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Committed Bytes In Use"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            },
            "Network Interface": {
                "measurement": [
                    "Bytes Sent/sec",
                    "Bytes Received/sec",
                    "Packets Sent/sec",
                    "Packets Received/sec"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Paging File": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Usage"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "PhysicalDisk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Disk Time",
                    "Disk Write Bytes/sec",
                    "Disk Read Bytes/sec",
                    "Disk Writes/sec",
                    "Disk Reads/sec"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Processor": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Processor Time",
                    "% Idle Time",
                    "% Interrupt Time"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "statsd": {
                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60,
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "service_address": ":8125"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While my common-config.toml is:

```
# This common-config is used to configure items used for both ssm and cloudwatch access
 
 
## Configuration for shared credential.
## Default credential strategy will be used if it is absent here:
##            Instance role is used for EC2 case by default.
##            AmazonCloudWatchAgent profile is used for the on-premises case by default.
# [credentials]
#    shared_credential_profile = "{profile_name}"
    shared_credential_file= "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.aws\\credentials"
 
## Configuration for proxy.
## System-wide environment-variable will be read if it is absent here.
## i.e. HTTP_PROXY/http_proxy; HTTPS_PROXY/https_proxy; NO_PROXY/no_proxy
## Note: system-wide environment-variable is not accessible when using ssm run-command.
## Absent in both here and environment-variable means no proxy will be used.
# [proxy]
#    http_proxy = "{http_url}"
#    https_proxy = "{https_url}"
#    no_proxy = "{domain}"
```

When I try running & "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1" -a fetch-config -m onPremise -c ssm:AmazonCloudWatch-windows -s, I get the following:

```
****** processing amazon-cloudwatch-agent ******
Got Home directory: C:\Users\Administrator
I! Set home dir windows: C:\Users\Administrator
I! SDKRegionWithCredsMap region:
Unable to determine aws-region.
2023/07/17 14:18:45 E! Please make sure the credentials and region set correctly on your hosts.
Refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
E! Please make sure the credentials and region set correctly on your hosts.
Refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
Fail to fetch the config!
NativeCommandExitException: C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1:303
Line |
 303 |          & $CWAProgramFiles\config-downloader.exe --output-dir "${JSON …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Program "config-downloader.exe" ended with non-zero exit code: 1.
```

It happens that my laptop dows not use Administrator account. The account is named Lenovo. So I believe that is causing the error.

What can I do from here, to CloudWatch Agent does look into the right home dir?

I tried changing profiles, referencing config.json locally, most of possible changes on quotes for paths into both config.jason and common-config.toml